How to avoid duplication of string literal text in functions that accept different width characters / strings?
I frequently need to create string manipulation functions in C++. My APIs tend to be written to accept std::basic_string<T> (effectively), but I also want to accept std::basic_string_view<T> when it makes sense. There have been a few pains in adopting string_views which I've worked around, but with literals I have found only pain.
Now, being a good developer, I abhor both inline literals and code duplication.
I've found myself trying to write this:
template <typename CharType>
constexpr const CharType* HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World!";

This doesn't work, specifically since if CharType is not char I need a u or U or L in there.
I would love a solution that looks like this:
template <typename CharType>
static const CharType* HELLO_WORLD = <CharType>"Hello World!";

My current alternative require macros that create structs which specialize macros:
#define DEFINE_STRING_LITERAL(name, str)                 \
    template <typename CharType>                         \
    struct name {};                                      \
                                                         \
    template <>                                          \
    struct name<char> {                                  \
        static constexpr const char* value = str;        \
    };                                                   \
                                                         \
    template <>                                          \
    struct name<wchar_t> {                               \
        static constexpr const wchar_t* value = L##str;  \
    };                                                   \
                                                         \
    template <>                                          \
    struct name<char16_t> {                              \
        static constexpr const char16_t* value = u##str; \
    };                                                   \
                                                         \
    template <>                                          \
    struct name<char32_t> {                              \
        static constexpr const char32_t* value = U##str; \
    };

Which gets defined like this:
DEFINE_STRING_LITERAL(HELLO_WORLD ,"value");

and used like this:
HELLO_WORLD<CharType>::value

It's okay, and I can push the macro into a header somewhere and forget about it. But I don't like the definition syntax. It doesn't look like a definition, and then trying to find where it's defined with static tools if I need to change it is a headache. Also, it doesn't get type-deduced, which makes resulting code difficult to read.
The compiler knows which literal prefixes are associated with which types. I know this because it won't compile if I mess it up. So, is there any way to avoid that struct specialization and get something closer to the one-liner I'd love to see?
If anyone has a better solution that reads more like standard C++, instead of using a macro to define a type on the fly, that would be awesome.
P.S. I could probably create a constant class that has it's own literal syntax and stores a char*, but then I need to copy the strings instead of letting the compiler manage it. I'd also love if these were truly static literals, since I can't use dynamic const CharType* as values in template parameters.

I miss some requirements, do the input strings need to support encoding/multibyte characters or will you string literals basically be chars in the  ASCII range?

I was thinking along these lines : https://onlinegdb.com/TWWUMHJ25

@PepijnKramer that doesn't handle MBCS. Specifically, all UTF variations are MBCS. Encoding conversion is already a pain in the neck. Making it constexpr is just putting salt on a bleeding wound.

@Red.Wave I am totally aware of that, that's why the overload conversion functions should be added. And also why I didn't post it as an answer (it is a MACRO-less direction)

@PepijnKramer My take from your sample code was one by one substitution.

First, define a compile-time string class template that initializes an array of each character type:
template <std::size_t N>
class ct {
  std::tuple<char[N], wchar_t[N], char8_t[N], char16_t[N], char32_t[N]> arrays;

 public:
  consteval ct(const char (&literal)[N]) {
    std::apply(
        [&](auto &...array) { (..., std::ranges::copy(literal, array)); },
        arrays);
  }

  ...
};

Next, define a method that returns a view of a given character type:
  template <class Char>
  consteval std::basic_string_view<Char> view() const {
    return {std::get<Char[N]>(arrays), N - 1};
  }

To use it, just define a constant:
inline constexpr ct test = "Jon Skeet";

static_assert(test.view<char>() == "Jon Skeet"sv);
static_assert(test.view<wchar_t>() == L"Jon Skeet"sv);
static_assert(test.view<char8_t>() == u8"Jon Skeet"sv);
static_assert(test.view<char16_t>() == u"Jon Skeet"sv);
static_assert(test.view<char32_t>() == U"Jon Skeet"sv);

Try it on Compiler Explorer

Thanks. I want to try to avoid storing multiple copies of the data.
There's no problem with this from functionally solving my issues, but eventually I want the same guarantees as a template constexpr--i.e. that I only get bytes in my object code for the types that are instantiated.
I'm not sure that's possible yet without new C++ features.

Also, based on comments in the original question, this is doing a naive copy which can only be used in the ascii range. This is good enough for what I typically do, but for a general purpose utility, that's something that needs to be accounted for. Maybe a static_assert(c < 128) somewhere.

We can create a string literal that stores both narrow and wide strings.
The trick is to use the compile-time string literal trick, but populate both a char and wchar_t buffer.  Then support pointers to both.
Next, make these compile-time literals live in a type as non-type template arguments.  Store a static copy of them within the class, and return pointers to whichever buffer is needed.
You are going to write your code using both narrow and wide strings - the type will be shared, so only instantiated once.
Ie, something like:
static_str< "abc 123"_both >{}

creates static_str class that can implicitly be converted to anything that consumes either a char const* or a wchar_t const*.  Its state lives in its type, so two copies of static_str< "abc 123"_both >{} share underlying buffers (instances are stateless).
I'm guessing a few dozen lines of code, some of it tricky and using relatively new standard versions.
First, look into compile time strings; get "hello"_ct syntax working.  You'll find that storing both a char and wchar_t buffer is easy.  (keywords here are "user defined literals" for _ct syntax, and compile time strings; you can get at the buffer length at compile time and pass it to your compile-time string-buffer mangement class as a non-type template parameter (so it can size a fixed size array), then constexpr copy the characters over.)
Then static_string<auto ct_string>, where it stores the ct_string as a static variable and supports cast-to char const* and wchar_t const* if and only if ct_string does.
For ease of use, you'll want to support more than just cast-to char-pointer maybe - cast to anything constructible from char-pointer is a more generous version.  OTOH, a simple call to .get<CHAR_TYPE>() that returns the CHAR_TYPE const* version is less futzy magic.
I'm off for the weekend, but I think writing this would be fun.  Just gotta go.  If you have issues, ping me and I'll see what I can write up.
